# Show first occurrence of a 'space' in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sum

[image]

Here is what I am trying to do with this Restaurant Specials Table:

- Show  record 205 to return the total number of characters for Col3.
- Print  record 203 to return the first occurrence of a space in Col3.
- Display record 201 to return the date as CCYYMMDD from the Col2.

So far, I wrote these and trying to correct the syntax -

```
SELECT SUM(col3)
FROM dbo.Specials
Where col1 = 205

SELECT Top(' ', Col3)
FROM dbo.Specials
Where col1 = 203

SELECT Col2(DATE, CCYYMMDD)
FROM dbo.Specials
WHERE Col1 = 201
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For total number of characters use [`DATALENGTH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx)

```
SELECT DATALENGTH(col3)
FROM dbo.Specials
Where col1 = 205
```

[`CharIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) can give you the location of the first instance of a character in a string.

```
SELECT CHARINDEX(' ', col3)
FROM dbo.Specials
Where col1 = 203
```

To select the date as [`CCYYMMDD`](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic264177-8-1.aspx)

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(8), Col2, 112) 
FROM dbo.Specials
Where col1 = 201
```

Comment: I would have used len() for the first one in that I had never heard of datalength.

Comment: Thanks Paqogomez. It worked fine, but without the 'semi-colon' before FROM

Comment: @DanBracuk `len` works fine for varchar, but `datalength` has the benefit of handling varchar, varbinary, text, image, nvarchar, and ntext. And as OP didnt specify.....